# Fixed element—text won't go to second line

Tags: css, css-position

See here: https://www.invigorlaw.com/practice-areas/securities/ at a width of 1100 pixels or there about.

Panel on right side of screen looks good until you scroll down, then text goes from multiple line to one line and you can't see all of the text.

Only difference between elements I can tell is the top is static and the bottom is fixed.

Any advice on how to get the text to display on multiple lines would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Once it gets position:static; you also need to give it a set width.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Schedule a Meeting" button?

Comment: I'm not specifically talking about the schedule a meeting button, but I probably want to get that on two lines too. I'm more talking about the links above that like "recent corporate finance posts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this is your CSS

`ul.sidenav-ul { width: 237px; }`

That's the quick dirty efficient fix, what happens is that when `position: fixed` kicks in, the element is taken out of context (that's why you have z-index) so you can think of it as 3D in a way. Your affix there had `width: 100%` and `position: static;` and because of that it will never go more than the viewport, but with `absolute, fixed, relative` they can, and the text stretched the whole container. Limiting the text whole list to some width will make all elements inside stick to that, thus your text will look the same.

This is a good resource to learn this: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: This is going to work for me. Thank you. I'm going to have to set different widths for different viewport sizes, but that's easy enough. I appreciate your help!